# disable dates using an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, haml, uidatepicker

The following is not working because `@only` is `undefined` (stated 30 times in the log). I guess the function is executed out of the scope, but I don't understand why and how to solve this.

```
class DateDisabler

  constructor: (@only) ->

  beforeShowDay: (date) ->
    console.log @only
    if @only == date.getDate()
      [true, 'available', 'This date is a good date']
    else
      [false, 'unavailable', 'This date is NOT good']

jQuery ->
  $('.datepicker').each (i, e) ->
    dates = $(e).data('only')
    disabler = new DateDisabler dates
    $(e).datepicker({beforeShowDay: disabler.beforeShowDay})
```

Also I'd like an opinion if you think this is a good approach. I'm trying to get an html `div` to handle everything with the following:

```
.datepicker{data: {only: 5}}
```

[Here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecoologic/6LNHY/). Sorry for some reason it doesn't run there(if you know...), but at least there's html and js for whom prefer it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex is right about the underlying cause of the problem so you could inline the callback function but the more idiomatic way to get around the `this` problem in CoffeeScript is to use a [fat-arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) when you define the callback function:

```
beforeShowDay: (date) =>
  #...
```

That will bind the function to the context that you're expecting it to have. Also, you can use CoffeeScript on http://jsfiddle.net/ by selecting it in *Panels* in the sidebar.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Ztgsq/

Comment: works like a charm and I got the point. thanks a lot @mu! I learned I lot from your answers here in SO.